# Tried to hide any error messages, but it still appears

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using php 5.2.13 and Oracle database.

And I'm trying to hide error messages, but doesn't work.

I tried to...

add this code to the page where an error occurs

```
ini_set(display_errors,0);
```

set an option in `php.ini`

```
display_errors = Off
```

...and what else should I do?? I thought I had done enough.

And the error message is coming from Oracle like this;

```
ORA-01400 cannot insert NULL into .....
```

I wonder if there's any modules in php that display error messages..?

thanks.

Comment: If the errors keep coming back to haunt you, they probably want you to actually fix them instead of hiding them.

Comment: BoltClock// But I'm intentionally making this error to check it's hided or not.

Comment: Honestly, I'm violating the security policies. I have to hide it. Because the error shows the whole query.

Comment: Deckard, why would you do that? Intentionally hiding errors for any reason is simply bad practice; you should be working on fixing things so that there are no errors, and those you can't prevent should be handled instead of hidden. And "violating the security policies"? Are you trying to SQL inject into someone else's site or something?

Comment: Show the code. If you have something like `query() or die( ... )` it won't be affected by PHP settings.

Comment: No, I mean, the security dept. of my firm is ordering me to hide this error message.

Comment: They found this by modifying request packet(?) or something.. For a normal user, they can't see it, because the javascript prevents user from skipping specific fields.

Comment: Well, instead of obscuring the error you could just make sure you don't get the error even with incomplete input.

Comment: But if you *REALLY* need to hide it (although be sure to fix it first), try adding the `@` operator: `$result = @query(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a PHP error, but a Oracle error, your column can't be null - you need to specify a value. That's why your display_error's doesn't hide this error.

I have to emphasize - like others in the comments - that the only good error is a fixed one.

Comment: A tester found this problem, by modifying request params. Which means that this sites is weak to the attack.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `LOG ERRORS INTO` on your DML, this should allow you to dump your errors to a table for later inspection.

see: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=329

and: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH